# How can I return the value of disabled drop-down field after submit?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I have a drop down field that if any items of it selected, it would be disabled, after that I submit the form, but then (after submitting) the drop down field doesn't have any value, I want to have a value after submit but my drop down field is empty.

Thanks for any help,
(sorry for my English)

Hi again. My problem still remains but thanks anyway; to make it more clear there is my code:

```
code:  <tr>
  <td class="tbl_entry_form_title"><%=DTask.LU_TECHNICIAN_TITLE%> :</td>
 <td class="tbl_entry_form_input">
<c:if test="${isTechnicianAdmin eq false}">
<c:forEach var="current" items="${technicianTitleItems}">
 <c:if test="${current.value eq taskBadrItem.lu_technician_title}">
<input name="lu_technician_title" value="${current.value}" onclick=" 
 <c:if test="${salesCustomerResult > 0}">alert('something')</c:if> 
 "/></c:if>
 </c:forEach></c:if><c:if test="${isTechnicianAdmin eq true}">
 <select name="lu_technician_title" class="select_box" onclick=" <c:if 


  test="${salesCustomerResult > 0}">alert('something')</c:if> ">
 <c:forEach var="current" items="${technicianTitleItems}"><option 
 value="<c:out value="${current.value}" />"<c:if test="${current.value 
 eq taskBadrItem.lu_technician_title}"> selected="selected"
 </c:if>>


 <c:out value="${current.title}"/></option></c:forEach></select>
</c:if></td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming that you use javascript to disable the dropdown, you can copy the selected value to a hidden field so it will be submitted with the form

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the value of a disabled field. One thing you could do is that save the selection of the select box in a hidden field through javascript and then you can read the value of that hidden field after the form is submitted.

**Example:**

```
<select name="whatever" id="whatever" onchange="document.getElementById('hdn').value = this.value;">
  <option value="value">Value</option>
  <option value="value">Value</option>
  <option value="value">Value</option>
<select>

<input type"hidden" id="hdn" />
```

Now in your script, you can read the value of selected option though `hdn` hidden field name.

**Note:** Using Javascript inside HTML markup is bad, however you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.org) for unobtrusive javascript.

**jQuery Example:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#whatever').change(function(){
    $('#hdn').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

In this case, you don't need to put javascript code in the html (select box in this example).

Hope that helps.